# converting multidimensional array slice operation from python to C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, dimension

I have following code snippet (which is part of a function) in python:

```
def decode_netout(netout, anchors, obj_thresh, net_h, net_w):
        # print("netout print: ", netout.shape, netout[0])
        grid_h, grid_w = netout.shape[:2]
        nb_box = 3
        netout = netout.reshape((grid_h, grid_w, nb_box, -1))
        nb_class = netout.shape[-1] - 5
        boxes = []
        netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])
        netout[..., 4:]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., 4:])
        netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4][..., np.newaxis] * netout[..., 5:]
        netout[..., 5:] *= netout[..., 5:] > obj_thresh
```

Here netout is array with 13, 13, 255 which is converted to 13, 13, 3, 85.
Now considering following statement,

```
netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])
```

If I need to covert this function code to C++ equivalent, what is the best way to write this code. In C++, netout is an array of float.
thanks and regards,
-sunil puranik

Comment: In C++, is `netout` just a 1D vector of length 43095?  If so, the reshaping is just a matter of doing the dimension computation differently.  The vector operations are all going to turn into loops, unless you are using a mathematics library like `eigen`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a high-performance library is recommended here (for example `Eigen`, `PyTorch`, `ArrayFire` or other libraries). If you want to do it yourself, it goes like this for `netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])` as an example:

```cpp
struct Array
{
    std::vector<size_t> shape;
    std::vector<float> data;
};

float sigmoid(float input)
{
    // return sigmoid function of input
}

void some_operation(Array &array)
{
    size_t Y = 1, X = array.shape.back();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.shape.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        Y *= array.shape[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Y; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            array.data[i * X + j] = sigmoid(array.data[i * X + j]);
        }
}
```

Here the `some_operation` function takes in an array and since the last dimension is important to us, the rest get flattened out. So we have two dimensions `Y, X`. Now we can iterate over the data and do the operation we want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If I need to use pytorch library, where can I find the documentation on multi-dimensional array processing with pytorch in C++? Or can I get a C++ library where python operations are defined as new operators?

Comment: You can look at the documentations and getting started pages of the libraries I mentioned to get started. For PyTorch, download libtorch from [here](https://pytorch.org/). The C++ interface of the library is very close to the Python interface. There are also C++ tutorials for getting started.